# Vim + tmux: background with different colors

Tags: vim, macos-sierra, tmux, iterm2

Does anyone know why when I'm within tmux, the background is darker on the right side and lighter on the left side?

[image]

Comment: Please try to add this set -g default-terminal "xterm" to your .tmux file

Comment: Thanks @RaviGehlot. Didn't work.

Comment: Is your terminal using 256? Run this: tput colors What number do you see?

Comment: Yes. I set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Put

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color" in .tmux.conf

and

xterm-256color in the iTerm 2 settings.

Comment: I've already done that. In fact, I used this dotfiles: https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles

Comment: That's pretty much my tmux conf: https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux/tmux.conf

Comment: Do you have any TERM setting inside of ~/.vimrc?

Comment: Nope. I would guess it has to do with the colorscheme and my iterm2 colors. the funny thing is, this problem only happens when I'm within tmux.

Comment: Are you running that over SSH?

Comment: Nope. I'm not. Just normal use.

Comment: Backup the settings for your terminal and then reset the terminal. Start fresh. Give that a try.